# How to apply filter to an image for instance of P5 in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, p5.js

I'm hoping this is a very straight forward question but I haven't been able to get to the bottom of it. I'm using a react-P5-wrapper to create my P5 canvas in react (`https://github.com/slin12/react-p5-wrapper`) and I want to apply a filter to an image, which I normally would do in P5 like `image.filter(GRAY)`, however I can't get it to work when P5 is an instance in React.

My sketch function looks like

```
function sketch(p5) {
        let hair;

        p5.setup = () => {
            p5.createCanvas(600, 600);
            hair = p5.loadImage(~/localpath/hairURL);
        }
      
        p5.draw = () => {
            p5.image(hair, 0, 0);
        };
      }
```

I would have thought I could do something as easy as `p5.image(hair,0,0).filter(p5.GRAY);` in my draw function, but that doesn't work. Gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')`

I could just use `p5.filter(p5.GRAY);` as a separate line in draw() - which works - however that applies the filter over the whole canvas, whereas I want to just apply it over one of the images. I will have multiple images and want to apply different filters to each one.

p5.image(hair,0 ,0).p5.filter(p5.GRAY) doesn't work either (thought I would try even if it didn't make much sense)

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you've confused the function [`p5.image()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/image), which draws an image and returns undefined, and the [`p5.Image`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image) class, which *is* an image and returns an object with methods such as [`p5.Image.filter()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/filter). `p5.Image.filter` is also a mutating mode setter that returns undefined, so it's not something you'd want to chain anywhere.

Also, the `p5` prefix in instance mode only applies to global p5 functions, not methods called on local objects like vectors and images that aren't part of the global p5 API namespace.

Here's the correct usage:

```js
new p5(p => {
  let img1;
  let img2;

  p.preload = () => {
    img1 = p.loadImage("https://picsum.photos/200/200");
    img2 = p.loadImage("https://picsum.photos/200/202");
  };

  p.setup = () => {
    p.createCanvas(700, 410);
    p.background(0);

    img1.filter(p.GRAY);
    p.image(img1, 0, 0);
    
    // should be unfiltered
    p.image(img2, 200, 0);

    p.noLoop();
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are trying to do will be possible with your current approach.

[In the documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/filter) for `p5.filter(...)` it states the function "Applies a filter to the canvas" and there's no indication it can be constrained to an image or area of the canvas.

FYI, `p5.image(...)` [doesn't return anything](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/image), so calling any function on the result like `p5.image(...).filter(...)` will always get the undefined error you are getting.

### Edit

[Actually the class](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image) `p5.Image` has it's own `filter` function.
So if you call

```
hair = loadImage(...)
//then
hair.filter(...)
```

And then later call `image(hair, 0, 0)`, that should work.